# How to access inApp Purchase Products in App without declaring thier identifier in code end?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

As I am working on inApp Purchase and follow some links and tutorials for their implementation. As I found that what product identifier we added in iTunes, it require to add in code end too...so it access in our app.

As I try to comment all the identifiers in code side and run the app, no inApp Purchase Products are visible. When I uncomment that code after run app shows all those which are added in code.

My Query is, any way that I add the items in iTunes is directly accessed in app without declaring them in code.

Here is a screenShot:

[image: ios]

Here in iTunes added 6 plan

Now in Code if I add their identifier are only visible in app not all.

How can I achieve this.
Any Suggestion Please....

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correct, your way make some api for getting identifiers.
Apple have recommendations about this

[Apple doc - Loading In-App Product Identifiers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/loading_in-app_product_identifiers)

> Retrieve Product IDs from Your Server Store the product identifiers
>   from your server if:
>
> You update the list of in-app products frequently, without updating
>   your app. For example, games that supports additional levels or
>   characters should fetch the product identifiers list from your server.
>
> The products consist of delivered content.
>
> Your app or product requires a server.
>
> Host a JSON file on your server with the product identifiers. For
>   example, the following JSON file contains three product IDs

I hope this helps for your issue